# App can't be opened when accessing with another user

Tags: macos, mac, applications, user-account

I have a mac that runs Fusion360 under one user. I now want to use the program from the other user but I get an error that the application is not supported.

That's weird because it runs without problems on the same machine with the initial user.

[image]

This problem seems quite weird. I'm happy to provide more information.

[image]

Comment: Is this an M1 Mac? - Do you have Rosetta enabled for that user?

Comment: No its an intel iMac

Comment: You should show use the apps permissions. click on the app. do command + i do it on a few apps and see what is different from an app that doesn't load and one that does.  Are you sure this app is meant to be used my multiple users.

Comment: @historystamp: Thanks I'll give that a shot